# Kotlin equivalent of Swift's sorted(by:)

Tags: swift, sorting, kotlin

I am not sure how to use a function similar to Swift's sorted(by:). I am trying to use Kotlin's sortedby() function but I am missing something.

Test is a model and tests is the array to sort.

Swift code to port:

```
let sortedArray = tests.sorted(by: { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
        let lhsDisplayName = self.getDisplayName(Test: lhs).capitalized
        let rhsDisplayName = self.getDisplayName(Test: rhs).capitalized
             return lhsDisplayName < rhsDisplayName })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess it should look like:

```
val tests = arrayOf("a", "B", "c", "d")
val sorted = tests.sortedBy { it -> getDisplayName(it).capitalize() }
```

Comment: So in Kotlin the closure/lambda takes a single element, and returns a normalized version of that element that can be compared with other elements? What if the objects in the array can't be compared with each other by default?

Comment: i that case you need a comparator e.g. http://kotlination.com/kotlin/kotlin-sort-list-of-objects-with-comparator-example

Answer (score 2):

Without having to capitalize the strings, you could use [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-c-a-s-e_-i-n-s-e-n-s-i-t-i-v-e_-o-r-d-e-r.html):

```
val tests = arrayOf("c", "B", "a", "d")
val sorted = tests.sortedWith(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
println(sorted) //[a, B, c, d]
```

Depending on how you have translated `getDisplayName(Test:)` function, you could use [`compareBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html) which takes a variable number of functions to sort by:

```
val sortedArray = tests.sortedWith(compareBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER, getDisplayName))
```